# Converting None latin characters into latin charcters in Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-server

I would like to use a function convert none Latin characters to Latin characters when producing a report from the data in the DB, which is Azure SQL Server. i.e. input the original name and output the name with the latin characters

For example if a name is written with one of the following:

```
Ä ä À à Á á Â â Ã ã Å å Ǎ ǎ Ą ą Ă ă Æ æ
```

I would like to replace the non-latin characters with `A` or `a`.

If a name is written with one of the following:

```
Ç ç Ć ć Ĉ ĉ Č č
```

I would like to replace the non-latin characters with `C` or `c`.

This is the list of non-latin characters to replace. It is quite long so I am asking if anyone knows a smart way to do this rather than brute force using so many replace operations:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Look at `TRANSLATE`; then nest them? Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI` in your `SELECT` statements.

For example:

```
SELECT 'Ä ä À à Á á Â â Ã ã Å å Ǎ ǎ Ą ą Ă ă Æ æ' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI as [result]
```

It will work for almost all characters specified in your image except few like `Æ` and `æ`. You can use `TRANSLATE` for remaining characters if it is really required.

You can read more from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thanks. Not sure though how I would use Translate for those given the replacing characters are actually two characters. Wouldnt I need to translates?
Translate (@first_name,'Ææ','Aeae')

Comment: checkout this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/82360). Make a note that TRANSLATE is available in SQL Server 2017 and later. Use REPLACE if you are using earlier SQL Server 2017

Comment: Thanks, cant I use it like this in a function: 
@first_name_without_none_latin_chaaracters = Translate (@first_name,'Ææ','Aa') COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS

Cause I need it in a function not just a select.

Comment: Then turn it into a function, @user1372603 . The solution you have is more than simple to make into a function if you must. Why do you need a scalar function to do this though? Unless you have SQL Server 2019 I recommend against that decision due to the lack of inlining.